# Matrix in Tikz with centered Numbers (especially negative numbers)

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, matrices, center

I've got the following problem with negative numbers in my matrix:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
inner ysep=0pt, column sep=0.8em, row sep = 0.65em,
nodes={inner sep=0.3em,text width=0.85em,align=center}
]
{
    1 & 2 & 1 &  0\\
    0 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
};
\path ($(m-1-3.north east)+(0.3em,0)$) edge[thick] ($(m-3-3.south east -| m-1-3.north east)+(0.3em,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried anchor = center as well as align = center, but the negative number still looks awkward. Its not centered..

Which option am I missing? Ty for your help!

Comment: Please tell us which packages you load.

Comment: Right: Please include the preamble and document-statements. Things will go faster, should you even include a screenshot of your current result ;-) / Thanks

Comment: Aside : Is there a reason for not using one of the matrix-like environments of the `amsmath` package -- such as `matrix`, `pmatrix`, and `bmatrix` -- to create the matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not with the text alignment, what you did is correct on this side. The issue comes from the text width which is too small for -2 to fit in. Reduce you inner sep and use a larger text width:

[image: matrix with centred figures]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
        left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
        inner ysep=0pt, column sep=0.8em, row sep = 0.65em,
        nodes={inner sep=0.1em,outer sep=0,text width=1.2em,align=center}
        ]
        {
            1 & 2 & 1 &  0\\
            0 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        };
        \path ($(m-1-3.north east)+(0.3em,0)$) edge[thick] ($(m-3-3.south east -| m-1-3.north east)+(0.3em,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `inner ysep` and `inner xsep` separately if you want to get a wider or a higher matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [Here](https://www.guitex.org/home/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=5&id=66105&Itemid=71&lang=it)

[image]

The photo comes from [Tikz PGF Manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) Page 143.

Try to combine your and this code.

Best Regards